# PHP - set session variable to expire after 30 minutes

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I expire a PHP session after 30 minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes)

I have a session

```
$_SESSION['uid'];
```

Is there a simple script to end this session after 30 minutes?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: not a duplicate, there is a difference between a "session variable" and a "session", their expiration are two different topics

Answer (score 4):

```
// Inialize session
session_start('admin');
// set timeout period in seconds
$inactive = 30;
// Check, if user is already login, then jump to secured page
if (isset($_SESSION['admin'])) {
    $session_life = time() - $_SESSION['admin'];
    // Jump to secured page
    header('Location: securedpage.php');
    if($session_life > $inactive) {
        session_destroy();
        // Jump to Logout page
        header("Location: logout.php");
    }
}
$_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
```

Comment: PHP - set session variable to expire after 30 minutes  
$inactive = 30; // the value in seconds.  
  
For 30 minutes.  
$inactive = 1800;